# Incorporate case statement in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

My requirement is as follows: I need to extract all companies data, which has similar name in table (first 3 words should occur in the name,can be in middle)  as the input company name.

My query is working fine for data where name has more than 3 words ,but *for less or equal to 3 it's failing*.

I didn't get how to incorporate conditions in where clause.

My query is as below

```
select regno,name from ereg 
where 
(name  like '%' +(
 SELECT SUBSTRING(name, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', name, CHARINDEX(' ', name, CHARINDEX(' ', name, 0)+1)+1)) matchingwrd
FROM ereg where regno='C2113-UPD01')+'%')
```

script is as below

```
CREATE TABLE ereg(
    regnoINT, name VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO ereg (regno,name)  
values 
('C2113-UPD01','future company Ltd'),  
('C2223-UPD01','MY future company Ltd Corp'),  
('C2113-UPD01','Prime Private Furnishings housing Ltd  '),  
('C26903-UPD01','My Prime Private Furnishings Service   '),
```

**for example,its working fine for regno='C2113-UPD01' and gives output -->>'C26903-UPD01','My Prime Private Furnishings Service

but if input is 'C2113-UPD01' My query fails and not able to fetch 'C2223-UPD01' company data**

Comment: FYI its a `case expression` not a `case statement`

Comment: column "regno" is defined as int. Your values are char. Something is wrong with your example.

Comment: What do you mean with "first 3 words"? At am minimum you should have a sort criteria for that. Maybe a window function will help?

Comment: Please provide sample data *and* desired results.

Answer (score 1):

Your table data insert script, the data and the script all seems to be not taken from a working version. I had to clean everything.

What I did to get the 3 words is adding another  space in front of the name:
Still your query gave me trouble. But here is how I did that

```
;With cted as
(
Select regno, name, 
    SUBSTRING(name + ' ', 0, CHARINDEX(' ', name + ' ', CHARINDEX(' ', name + ' ', CHARINDEX(' ', name + ' ', 0)+1)+1)) as ThreeWords 
from ereg 
)
Select c1.regno, c1.name, c2.regno, c2.name 
from cted c1
inner join cted c2 on c2.name like    '%' + c1.ThreeWords + '%' and c1.regno <> c2.regno
Where  c1.regno='C2213-UPD01' -- or c1.regno='C2113-UPD01'
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=b4fa3f7a4af590753e04d5977dc2baa7)